# How to read executables stdout stderr from Java code?

Tags: java, stdout, stderr

AFAIK, one can run a command line executable from Java using `Runtime`. And even get error code with processes `WaitFor()`. But how can I read executables output? Both stdout and stderr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Runtime tr = Runtime.getRuntime();

try {
    Process p = tr.exec("c:\\a.bat");
    InputStream err = p.getErrorStream();
    InputStream std = p.getInputStream();
    //TODO here we go!
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This does not work.  The correct solution uses at least one more thread, two is better, to handle the asynchronous nature of co-processes.